# Best way to deploy similar AWS Cloud formation resources

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'd like to have a template with two very similiar Step Functions.

One would be something like this.

Task 1: Validation whether upstream dependencies are available

Task 2: *whatever*

...

Task 5: *whatever*

The other would just be tasks 2 through 5.

I saw that there is a Step type Pass which would be nice if I could just use the same step function string and change the type.

Unfortunately I won't be able to select template values or use any programmatic generation libraries because this is part of a build pipeline that I can't change.

Comment: Can you pass in an argument to the step function that tells it whether to do step 1 or not?

Comment: @JasonWadsworth, good suggestion.  I think that's what I'll have to do.  Just have the switch in the code itself.  I don't think Cloudformation lends itself to reuse of definitions.